# How to prevent bleeding on UV image textures in blender?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I created an object in blender and created a UV texture as PNG. However, even though I so carefully line up the edges of the object in the UV editor, I get this bleeding artifact (below). How do I prevent this?

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: This may be caused by the image quality. How large is your texture?

Comment: Seems to be a beveling issue, apply bevel modifier at first.

Comment: Thank you both! After exploring it a bit more, I realized I forgot to make room for the gap between faces in my UV.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that my object has "gutters" between each face. Therefore adding additional space between each face in my UV fixed the issue.